# Can't change Arch default editor

Tags: bash, editors, nvim

I want to set nvim(Neovim) as my default editor, I have tried to edit my `.bashrc` and add this two line:

```bash
export EDITOR=nvim
export VISUAL=nvim
```

and then

```bash
$ source .bashrc
```

but it didn't work. Proof:

```bash
$ sudo visudo
visudo: no editor found (editor path = /usr/bin/vi)
```

How can I set that correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` by default sanitizes your environment: variables you set for your user account won't be visible in the process started by `sudo`. You can run `sudo` with the `-E` (`--preserve-env`) flag:

```
sudo -E visudo
```

You can add `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` to the list of environment variables that `sudo` preserves by default by editing `/etc/sudoers` and adding:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "VISUAL EDITOR"
```

Or you can set `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` in `root`'s `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `--preserve-end` and `env_keep` you can set environment variables used by `sudo` and all user sessions in the `/etc/environment` file.

```
$ cat /etc/environment
EDITOR=nvim
VISUAL=nvim
```